# How add colourful table to Excel using COM introp?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

This is my code to generate Excel using COM interop.

```
 public static void ExportDataTableToExcel(DataTable dt, string filepath)
 {
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //create excel
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        //add excel workbook
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();

        //add worksheet to worlbook
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

        //Set the header-row bold
        ws.Range["A1", "A1"].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

        //Adjust all columns
        ws.Columns.AutoFit();

       //spit top row
        ws.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1;

        //freeze top row
        ws.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;

        int rowCount = 1;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            rowCount += 1;

            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                // Add the header the first time through
                if (rowCount == 2)
                {
                    ws.Cells[1, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                }

                ws.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();
            }
        }

        wb.SaveAs(@"C:\ErangaExcelTest.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue,
                                             misValue, misValue, misValue,
                                             Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue,
                                             misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

        wb.Close(missing, missing, missing);

        excel.Quit();
    }
```

This is the Excel which I get from this method.

[image]

I need a colourful table like this

[image]

What kind of modifications do I need to do have this kind of colourful Excel ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the font color and the background color for each cell. You are already setting the font to bold by:

```
ws.Range["A1", "A1"].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
```

Now the Font object has more properties. To set the font color use the [Range.Font.Color property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837437%28v=office.15%29.aspx). To set background color for a cell, see the [Range.Interior property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836210%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Specifically you want to set `Pattern` to `xlPatternSolid` and then set some color with `Color` property of the `Interior` object.

In VBA you can specify fonts with their RGB values:

```
range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

will set the font color of the range to red.

To change borders, use the [Range.Borders property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822605%28v=office.15%29.aspx). The link has an example code on how to use it.

Comment: is it possible to bold table border ?

Comment: Updated the answer with info on how to set the border.